# Can security JARS be loaded with Maven?

Tags: maven, jar

We have some unit tests that will fail unless you have two jars, local_policy.jar, and US_export_policy.jar in your $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security folder. I'm supposed to see if we can just put them in a project folder, then tell Maven to use them when it does a build("mvn install"). Maybe with something like the dependency tag? Yes, I know everyone should just install these in their $JAVA_HOME, but this is the task I've been asked to look into.

Answer (score 1):

You are speaking about Maven dependency scope. Documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). You can say to Maven use some libraries just for testing using "test" scope.

Answer (score -1):

You can add them as [Maven systemPath dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).

> **systemPath**
>
> is used only if the the dependency scope is system. Otherwise, the build will fail if this element is set. The path must be absolute, so it is recommended to use a property to specify the machine-specific path (more on properties below), such as ${java.home}/lib. Since it is assumed that system scope dependencies are installed a priori, Maven will not check the repositories for the project, but instead checks to ensure that the file exists. If not, Maven will fail the build and suggest that you download and install it manually.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- The groupId can be anything. Use your own groupId for example -->
        <groupId>anything</groupId>
        <artifactId>local_policy</artifactId>
        <!-- The version can be anything. Use the version of Java for example -->
        <version>7.0</version>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/security/local_policy.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- The groupId can be anything. Use your own groupId for example -->
        <groupId>anything</groupId>
        <artifactId>US_export_policy</artifactId>
        <!-- The version can be anything. Use the version of Java for example -->
        <version>7.0</version>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```